# javascript not working inside html div on slow internet

Tags: javascript, html

I am putting html content dynamically base on condition.

Inside html content i also have javascript in script tag.

My problem is on slow internet my javascript not load on page.

It's work fine on fast internet.

[image]
[image]

Comment: $(document).ready({});

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question as text.

Comment: @ACD your solution not work. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Code can't "not work" because of a bad network (if it is not trying to fetch remote data). Your jQuery library probably doesn't load. Please update the question and show the Network tab to see what fails.

Comment: Are you getting a specific error? My guess would be that your JS code is trying to access element with id `datepicker_55474` **before it actually loaded**. If this is the case, then your code should be wrapped inside `onload = function() { //your code here}`, or as @ACD mentioned.

Comment: Please add more details about error and where you loaded your datepicker library inside document?

Comment: you should ensure that before your html is your js loaded or not if the script tag comes when your page refresh you should wrapped your date picker code with document ready. and if your code comes through ajax response than you should append your code after date picker library load. also may possible some other js conflict(affect) your date picker js.

Answer (score 2):

The same case faced.
Try with `console.log()` before and after your script.
You can see log print but not display here. Means this happens because of date picker js does not load properly or display any error so your script goes to stop.
Please load data picker js properly so resolve our issue.

Comment: Yes. log print before script.